# I feel I am going to have a heart attack

Tags: phd

I am doing my PhD still in the beginning and one of colleague is so bitchy, he is from the hell, he has a good and strong relationship with the head of the lab, and always fabricate stories about me, and that I don't do that good in the lab... of course, when I speak the PI is so upset and never ever you can say he is lying, he is always right, and excellent... screaming and closing the line of zoom suddenly, I did not have the chance to defend myself... I tried to avoid this colleague, but in vain, he sent an email to supervisor faking up data about me and something did not happened at all... the PI send me an email that you are not doing well, I will report you ill-performance to committee, I asked for a call to defend myself, but they made their mind, although I had pictures of my work and everything is right... I am crying all the night, how someone could be so devil to destroy me and acclaim things did not happen. He is so jealous almost from everyone, but maybe because I had got recognition and multiples awards before joining their group, this postdoc is so jealous and want only him in the scene, I really tried to avoid and every encounter made a disaster after... I am so tired there are no other labs accepting students for the moment, I feel that I am going to have a heart attack, I am by myself in a foreign country and that is so hard, I really I feel I am going to have a heart attack even the ombudsman don't reply to my emails.

Comment: You need to take care of your well-being first. See a counselor or mental health professional. Take a break. Meet friends. Get enough sleep and some exercise. Spend time outdoors.

Comment: I wish! They ask for meeting today where they are going to humiliate me and next week they threatened me to present again... how can I, if I cannot find job here, I will be literally on streets, I am here only by myself, and other positions available... I cannot breathe, it is hard to describe, but I am screwed completely

Comment: @Erik You must find a way. A counsellor or mental health professional can help you.

Comment: Do you have an ally in the department? Someone senior you can discuss matters with? Perhaps someone who is close to your advisor and willing to liaise with them?

Answer (score 0):

When you're in a situation where you feel you have nowhere to turn, you need to go as high as possible till you get a fair hearing and positive changes start to happen. In academia, go to the head of your panel or your supervisor. If that doesn't make any difference, go to the head of your faculty or the committee. If that doesn't work, go higher still. If you are certain you are correct, that you are being misrepresented and that you can justify your position, you have nothing to lose by going as high as possible. Write to the director if you have to [you won't, but you get my meaning].

Do not worry about going over someone's head. If you have spoken to your supervisor/PI and they are not seeing the whole picture, you need to go above them. You should be able to justify why you have done this: you cannot perform in your work, you supervisors are not seeing the whole picture, vital information is being overlooked, your mental health is at stake and you are worried for your physical health. You are paying for this education, and this is no way to spend your money or time. Things will just get progressively worse if positive changes don't happen now.

Ombudsmen take a long time to respond. Weeks, sometimes months. And even then they may come back with a "sorry, we can't help" reply. If you hit a wall at the top with your communication, consider leaving and taking your research with you elsewhere. You should be able to justify why you have done at your next institution so if you can back yourself up with emails.

Research is supposed to be rewarding. Challenging, yes, but not to the point where you are worried for your physical health. I know some people think that PhDs and post-docs are everything, but they're not, they are just a part of your life. You need to change your plan of attack somewhat, and you can start by writing some emails to those higher up, but make sure what you say is factual rather than emotional. Try not to say something which you could regret later. State your case fairly and factually, what you have and haven't done, what has led to this point and why you felt writing to them was the only course of action to take. Good luck.

Comment: In many parts of the world, you don't pay for doing a PhD.

Comment: Great advice but I would add one additional point that you should be sure to document everything that happens or has happened in as much detail as possible.

Comment: This is terrible advice for the asker's situation.   The asker needs to consult a mental health professional and recover before doing any of these things.  Possibly consulting with a lawyer would be wise too.